# java - determining if a file is a link

Tags: java, file, symlink

How do you do it, or is it even possible?

I suppose you could fiddle with getCanonicalWhatever and the original path, but that's messy and I don't like it. Please include a definitive reason if you suggest it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the article [How to deal with filesystem softlinks/symbolic links in Java](http://www.onyxbits.de/content/blog/patrick/how-deal-filesystem-softlinkssymbolic-links-java)

In short, wait until Java 7 or do a little JNI method

Comment: Had to do the JNI method myself, around 2001 - been there, done that, have the code around here somewhere...